# Deep Population of an object that belongs to a Schema that is a value of an object in an array in Mongoose.

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, populate

I have the following Schema:

```
 const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    favoriteStreams: [
        {
            stream: {
              type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "Stream",
              unique: true
            },
            param: Number
        }
    ]
});
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to populate each stream. This code, and many variations that I've tried do not work.

```
User.findOne({_id: req.user._id})
       .populate({path: "favoriteStreams", populate: {path: "stream", model:"Stream"}})
```

The added level of separation has made it difficult for me. How would I get at each streams properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
User.findOne({_id: req.user._id})
.populate(path: "favoriteStreams.stream")
```

Comment: Haha. I copied your code to go test it, and have the exact same code there already as the last thing I tested.

Except for the curly brackets around the object. I still tried yours, because I thought, "Maybe Jay has some secret syntax knowledge." 

You do. I've seen it from you before.

Comment: The hard thing is the added layer of nesting.